# Which salesforce edition?

Tags: connected-apps, editions

I want to buy/subscribe to salesforce edition. I need to have a connected app that I will use for authenticating salesforce users on my third party webapp. The only reason I want to subscribe to salesforce is just to create a connected app. What are my options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a Developer Edition and park a Managed Package there with your Connected App. You only need a paid edition if you want to use it for your business (e.g. marketing/sales/support) as well as your LMO (License Management Org). There's no need to pay just to have a Connected App. Just remember to meet the minimum qualifications to avoid [being marked inactive and deleted](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.admin_de_org_expiration.htm&type=5).

Comment: for more background can you please reference my above comment. Also, Is it fine to use Developer edition just for connected app (not going to use for anything else) if I am going to get monetary benefit from my web app?

Comment: @explorer Yeah, I have a couple of my own, actually. It works great.

Comment: Thanks for confirming.  Also, if you have a any reference documentation that will be great!

Comment: @explorer A reference for what, exactly?

Comment: Just wondering if you know a place where it was mentioned that Developer Edition may be used for creating a connected app for third party webapps that are built for revenue generation.

Comment: @explorer You're thinking about this from the wrong direction. Even if you have a paid business org, that wouldn't necessarily be good enough for what you're trying to do. The Connected App doesn't care if it's in a paid org or free Developer Edition, but apps are supposed to be security-reviewed, and Connected Apps can be disabled if the app that uses it misbehaves. You'll want to look at the [partner hub](https://partners.salesforce.com/pdx/s/?language=en_US) for more information.

Comment: Gotcha. I will check partner hub. My app is not a managed package, it's a webapp that is written in Nodejs and hosted on Firebase. Basically, it works similar to CoderPad. Difference is users can execute apex and compile formula fields. Do you think it still needs to be security reviewed?

Comment: @explorer It doesn't *need* to, but like I said, there's a risk of your Connected App being suspended if you don't. Security Reviews are there to provide your subscribers with confidence that your app is secure with their data.

Comment: Makes sense.  Appreciate your time and insights. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

From https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.connected_app_overview.htm&type=5

> Connected Apps can be created in: Group, Professional, Enterprise, Essentials, Performance, Unlimited, and Developer Editions
>
> Connected Apps can be installed in: All Editions

A connected app is one thing, but to make it useful you probably want to be able to write Apex (the Salesforce proprietary, java-like OOP language). In which case you need at least the "Enterprise" edition.

Comment: Derek, I only need this connected app for authentication of the users in their own orgs. I don't use my org for anything else. I also may use the same for the monetary benefit in the future. so, wondering if Developer edition is suitable.

Comment: @explorer This is starting to sound like you want to be an ISV (Independent Software Vendor) and publish an App on Salesforce's AppExchange. I.E. You create a thing on Salesforce (which can make _callouts_ to external sites) that you then list on AppExchange (after going through the Security Review). The more details you can include in your question, the more accurate/useful the answers you'll get will tend to be.

Comment: Not sure If I go under ISV, but I am working on a webapp (not a managed package) and it's almost done. Basically, it works similar to CoderPad. Difference is users can execute apex and compile formula fields. So, I don't need a managed package like ISV's do.